# problem with jquery overriding link href

Tags: jquery

I have a div (`.questionsList`) that contains a link.  When the div is clicked, I have an element `#slider` that slides out. However, when the link inside the div is clicked, I want to follow that link. The problem is, when I click the link, the jquery slide effect is overriding the link href so the slider slides out and the link does nothing. How can I fix this?

This is the code I was using prior to recognizing the problem.

```
$(".questionsList").toggle(function() {       
    $('#slider').animate({ left: '375' }, 500);
}, function() {
    $('#slider').animate({ left: '0'}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Have you verified the href element is actually removed (using Firebug, for instance)?

Comment: That's the think, the jref element is not removed, I can see it on firebug.  The link is just not working because the jquery above is stopping it somehow?

Comment: There's something vaguely familiar about this. Can you post a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour has nothing to do with the piece of code you have shown.

I suspect you have either:

```
return false;
```

Or:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Remove any of these from the `click` handler for your div and your link should work.

Comment: I have neither of those the code I show above is actually what I have when the problem is occuring

Comment: @hubrid, the above code has to be inside some other code otherwise it will not execute when the div is clicked...

Comment: @hubrid that is odd. So there's no other code in the JS file? Can you show your HTML too then?